# Basic Visual Basic Program Error - Probably Variable Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am writing this program for visual basic that will determine a bill based off water usage. My problem is that all values I input come back as zero in the command prompt. Can anyone explain what's wrong with this code?

---

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System

module eurekawatercompany

  Sub Main ()
    ' Declare variables of problem
    Dim waterusage as double 
    Dim totalcharge as double

    ' Prompts for user to enter their water usage.
    Console.write ("Please enter your current water usage (cubic feet): ")
    waterusage = convert.toint32(console.readline())
      If (waterusage < 1000) then
      totalcharge = 15

      End If

      If (1000 > waterusage) and (waterusage < 2000) then
      totalcharge = 0.0175 * waterusage + 15

      End If

      else if (2000 < waterusage) and (waterusage > 3000) then
      totalcharge = 0.02 * waterusage + 32.5

      End If
      ' 32.5 is the price of exactly 2000cm^(3) of water

      else if (waterusage > 3000) then
      totalcharge = 70

      End If

    Console.out.writeline ("Total charge is: ")
      Console.out.writeline (totalcharge)


  End sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, your statement:

```
If (1000 > waterusage) and (waterusage < 2000) then
```

is equivalent to:

```
If (waterusage < 1000) and (waterusage < 2000) then
```

meaning that it's testing that `waterusage` is *both* less than 1000 *and* less than 2000 (ie, just that it's less than 1000). I think you may have meant something along the lines of:

```
If (waterusage > 1000) and (waterusage <= 2000) then
```

You'll notice I've used `<=` as well since your `if` statements don't handle the edge cases at all (2000 is neither less than, nor greater than, 2000 so entering 2000 would cause none of your original `if` statements to fire).

You'll also need to make similar changes to the `0 to 1000` and `2000 to 3000` cases.

---

I'm also not *entirely* certain that the:

```
:
End If
else if ...
```

construct is correct (unless VB.NET has changed *drastically* at the lower levels since the VB6 days (I know that there were a lot of changes but changing such a low-level thing as the workings of `if` would be unlikely). An `end if` closes off the *entire* `if` statement as far as I'm aware, so the `else` should be *between* the `if` and `end if`.

So I'd be looking at something like:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Imports System
Module EurekaWaterCompany

Sub Main ()
    Dim WaterUsage as double
    Dim TotalCharge as double

    Console.Out.Write ("Please enter your current water usage (cubic feet): ")
    WaterUsage = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.In.ReadLine())

    If (WaterUsage <= 1000) then
        TotalCharge = 15
    ElseIf (WaterUsage > 1000) and (WaterUsage <= 2000) then
        TotalCharge = 0.0175 * WaterUsage + 15
    ElseIf (Waterusage > 2000) and (WaterUsage <= 3000) then
        TotalCharge = 0.02 * WaterUsage + 32.5
    Else
        TotalCharge = 70
    End If

    Console.Out.WriteLine ("Total charge is: ")
    Console.Out.WriteLine (TotalCharge)
End sub

End Module
```

That code also has some minor fixes like properly specifying `Out` and `In` for the I/O, and using "proper" capitalisation, although it's not fully tested and may still have some syntax errors. The idea behind the code (basically the `if` statement) is still sound.

---

However, you may want to check your specifications.

When utilities charge for their resource, they tend to levy higher rates on the *excess* beyond a certain level, not the entire amount. In other words, I'd expect to see a charge of $15 on the *first* 1000 cubic feet and then 1.75 cents on each cubic foot *beyond* that, which would make your statements look more like:

```
ElseIf (WaterUsage > 1000) and (WaterUsage <= 2000) then
    TotalCharge = 0.0175 * (WaterUsage - 1000) + 15
```

That would make sense in this situation since you'd be charged 1.5c/ft<sup>3</sup> for the first thousand, 1.75c/ft<sup>3</sup> for the second thousand, and 2c/ft<sup>3</sup> for the third thousand, with a lower limit of $15 (you get charged for the first thousand no matter how much you actually use) and a fixed charge of $70 for anyone who uses more than three thousand cubic feet (sort of a penalty rate).

But, that's supposition on my part, from experience. It may be that your specifications say otherwise, in which case feel free to ignore this section.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try in the morning to see if it works.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for explaining so well. Also, you were correct about the math error.